# Unable to get URL from JSON, when I tried it is displaying undefined. any advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Unable to get URL from JSON, when I tried it is displaying `undefined`. any advice?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function a()
{
$.getJSON("https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/api/v1/serviceUrl/UDAY",function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data));});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="GET JSON" onclick="a()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JSON from which I am trying to get the URL Value

```
{
     "response": {
         "URL": "https://chm.tbe.taleo.net/chm02/ats/api/v1/"
     },
     "status": {
         "detail": {},
         "success": true
     }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? and I am not using function-as-variable declarations so shall I use a semicolon after a curly bracket I mean after a function declaration

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function a(){
$.getJSON("https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/api/v1/serviceUrl/UDAY",function(data) {  
            var innerHtml = "";
            document.getElementById("CWS_URL").href=(data.response.URL).substr(0,(data.response.URL).indexOf("ats"))+"ats/careers/jobSearch.jsp?cws=1&org=UDAY";
            });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id ="CWS_URL" >Careers</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In callback of `getJSON`, `alert(data.response.URL)`

Comment: What is displaying `undefined`? Your code sample works and you haven't explained what you've attempted, so it's really hard to explain what you've done incorrectly and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Complete sample:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $('#btn').click(function() {

            $.getJSON(
                'https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/api/v1/serviceUrl/CODE',
                function(data) {

                    alert(data.response.URL);
                }
            );
        });
    });  

</script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get JSON">
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/logual/mpmzpcfL/

Don't use pure JavaScript's event instructions when jQuery available. For example: `onclick="a()"`. Remove It from your HTML code.

Comment: It's helpful to explain why one should remove the HTML attribute... see http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/